# Estimating predictive accuracy of simulated data when comparing two independent datasets with different lenght (using R)

Tags: r, statistics, cross-validation

I have two independent datasets. One corresponds to simulated data (obtained using a computer model) and another one to observed data. They have different length (e.g. observed 48 data-points, and simulated 4000 data-points).

I want to estimate the predictive accuracy/performance of the simulated data.

So far, I have been using independent t-tests (unpaired) (Welch's t-test, and Bayes factor t-test) to evaluate if my simulated and observed data are statistically different. But I would like to know if in this case it is possible to use a Cross-validation method to estimate the averaged prediction error RSME (or performance metric) across folds.

Comment: I think this question is for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi @pyring, can you elaborate a bit more about how you simulate the data? Did you calculate the mean and standard deviation and use rnorm to get the simulated data points? In any case you can use qqplot to see the quantiles more or less agree between simulated and observed..

Comment: t.test doesn't make sense because you are testing for a difference in mean, but a pvalue > 0.05 or some cutoff doesn't tell you it is similar. Likewise, i don't see how RMSE (between what and what?) can tell you the simulated is close enough to observed

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf :). Thanks for your comment. I simulated some data using an agent-based model. This ABM can take a number of parameters. Each parameter combination yields a distribution of y (e.g. let's say simulated y). Then I ran an experiment and obtained a distribution of y under experimental conditions (let's say observed y). I have compared both distributions using t-tests and Bayes factor. But I would like to obtain a more precise metric to estimate model performance from the comparison of observed and simulated datasets.

Comment: Just do a qqplot between observed and simulated. t.test and Bayes only test the hypothesis they have different means. It does not tell you they have different distributions. For example, if one has high standard deviation than the others? E.g t.test(runif(100),rnorm(100)) gives you a non-significant pvalue, but they are totally different. Hope this is clear?

Comment: Yes. However, by using t-test and/ or Bayes I am at least testing the null hypthesis that the two mean values are equal, right? So at least, I am providing some information about how accurate is the model to yield equal mean values of y. Am I correct? I know that these tests do not tell anything about how equal/different are those distributions. Thanks for your answer. Still wondering if there is anything else I can do given the situation.